# Converting time 121.419419 to readable minutes/seconds

Tags: powershell, time

I'd like to calculate the time my script runs, but my result from get-date is in totalseconds.

How can I convert this to 31:14:12 behing hours:minutes:seconds?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
PS> $ts = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 1234567
PS> '{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}' -f $ts.Hours,$ts.Minutes,$ts.Seconds
06:56:07
```

or

```
PS> "$ts" -replace '^\d+?\.'
06:56:07
```

Comment: Thank you very much Shay! I ended up doing the following:

$start = (get-date)
 
write-host "Script Started at $start"
for ($i=1; $i -lt 5; $i++) {
    get-process | out-null
    sleep 1
    echo "My script goes here. Let me count to 5 for you: $i"
    }
$end = (Get-Date)

$timespan = new-timespan -seconds $(($end-$start).totalseconds)

$elapsed = '{0:00}h:{1:00}m:{2:00}s' -f $timespan.Hours,$timespan.Minutes,$timespan.Seconds

write-host "Time: $elapsed"

Comment: Yes, basically you get the start and end date and subtract one form another, the result is a timespan object which you can format using the -f operator (e.g $timespan = $start-$end; '{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}' -f $ts.Hours,$ts.Minutes,$ts.Seconds).

Comment: You Sir, have earned a "useful" :)

Answer (score 9):

All you have to do is use the `Measure-Command` cmdlet to get the time:

```
PS > measure-command { sleep 5}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 5
Milliseconds      : 13
Ticks             : 50137481
TotalDays         : 5.80294918981481E-05
TotalHours        : 0.00139270780555556
TotalMinutes      : 0.0835624683333333
TotalSeconds      : 5.0137481
TotalMilliseconds : 5013.7481
```

The above output itself might be good enough for you, or you can format it appropriately as the the output of Measure-Command is a TimeSpan object. Or you can use `ToString`:

```
PS > (measure-command { sleep 125}).tostring()
00:02:05.0017446
```

Comment: Great answer.  I had this same issue and .toString() was spot on.  To me it was better than parsing out each time value from the measure-command itself or converting time types. Thanks!